# Prevent form from submiting validate and submit normally

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a form which I want to validate client side. Its a small form so I tried to do this by myself without using any plugins. But If the form validates I want it to sumbit noramlly. E.g

```
$(documet).ready(function(){
    $(".myform").on('submit', function (event){
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent it from submitting
        validate = validateForm(); //function to validate fields
        if (validate){
            this.submit();//if everything is ok submit it normally
        }
    })
});
```

But the form won't submit itself. I believe it has to do with the event.preventDefault(). Doesnt the submit() method called after it undo the preventDefault()? Should i put the prevent default in

```
if (!validate){
    event.preventDefault();
}else{
    this.submit();
}
```

What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return true to submit form

```
if (!validate){
    event.preventDefault();
}else{
    return true;
}
```

or use `$(this).submit();`

or just leave with if condition no need of else

```
if (!validate){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work, I put preventDefault()inside if and still wont submit the form(no posting)

Comment: @Apostolos : check the function `validateForm()` return correctly

Comment: true. I had to check the validateForm(). The this submit created another problem...It got in to a loop :)

Answer (score 0):

We can use type="button" instead of type="submit" as follows

```
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit form">

function myFunction()
{
validate = validateForm();
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

Comment: but this won't prevent my form from submitting

Comment: Use type button and return false.function myFunction()
{
validate = validateForm();
return false;
}  check validform function and you can add return false; at the end of the function.